# Captcha for single page application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, captcha

I have a one-page application, which was made on asp.net mvc5. What is the best free captcha for an HTML page (not cshtml). All captcha that I can find are for cshtml page ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use google's reCaptcha. in a single page application you can display the captcha via javascript when ever you need it. you can than authenticate server-side via ajax.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/

there are plugins available for several backend environments like [asp.net](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/aspnet) or [classic asp](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/asp). but you can also implement the backend yourself through a simple api: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Thank you, will try to use reCaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

The one i use is google recaptcha its free and easy to implement.

http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/